# Cómo hacer que mi calculadora muestre en pantalla los signos de las operaciones en Python

Tags: python, poo, interfaz-gráfica, jupyter, calculo

para mi curso de POO en Python, hicimos una calculadora. Ahora, el profesor quiere que le agreguemos a ésta las operaciones con las 3 principales funciones trigonométricas, raíz cuadrada, factorial y potenciación, sin embargo, mi calculadora no muestra los signos de las operaciones que realiza y antes de agregar esas nuevas operaciones, quiero que muestre los signos. He tratado de hacer todo lo posible para que se muestren, pero nada me ha funcionado. Estoy usando Google Colab. Adjunto el código original.
[Código calculadora](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1E3nX3J5AftIJg5wV-TOnvji9h2e-s7-M?usp=sharing)

```
     # https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html
                    !pip install ipywidgets

                    import ipywidgets as widgets
                
                    import numpy as np
                    import math

                buttons=["C", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
         "7", "8", "9", ".", "+", "-", "x", "/", "=","^","sqrt","sin","cos","tg","!"]

            # Identifier ≠ String/Text
            # button+buttons[0]=widgets.button()
            cal_bt={}
            for button in buttons:
            cal_bt[button]=widgets.Button(description=button)
            # Placeholder is different than the argument value
            # Default value
            screen=widgets.Text(value="0")
            screen

            # Bash command to get a file from the internet
            
            # https://www.pngmart.com/files/22/Casio-Logo-PNG-Isolated-Pic.png
                                          !wgethttps://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4d/Casio_logo.svg/2560px-Casio_logo.svg.png

file = open("2560px-Casio_logo.svg.png", # Path + File Name + Extension
            "rb")                              # Read - Bytes
image = file.read()                            # Extracting all data from the file
logo= widgets.Image(
        value=image,                           # The extracted data from the file
        format='png',                          # File extension that you are using
        width=150,                             # Number of pixels on the X axis
        height=150,                            # Number of pixels on the Y axis
        )
logo
# On call function for our buttons 
def Get_description(obj_bt):
  a=obj_bt.description
  if screen.value=="0":
    if a==".":        #and a=="+" and a=="-" and a=="x" and a=="/" and a=="^" and a=="sin" and a=="cos" and a=="tg" and a=="sqrt" and a=="!":
      screen.value+=a
    else:
      screen.value=a
  elif a=="." and "." in screen.value:
    pass
  else:  
    screen.value+=a

# These two objects are hidden
__operation=widgets.Label(value="")
__memory=widgets.Label(value="")

def Get_operation(obj_bt):
  symbol=obj_bt.description
  if symbol in "+-x/^sqrtsincostg!":
      __operation.value=symbol
      __memory.value=screen.value
      screen.value="0"

def Get_result(obj_bt):
  try:
    a=float(__memory.value)
    b=float(screen.value)
    if  __operation.value=="+":
      screen.value=str(a+b)
    elif __operation.value=="–":
      screen.value=str(a-b)
    elif __operation.value=="x":
      screen.value=str(a*b)
    elif __operation.value=="/":
      screen.value=str(a/b)
    elif __operation.value=="^":
      screen.value=str(a**b)
    elif __operation.value=="sqrt":
      screen.value=str(a/b)
    elif __operation.value=="sin":
      screen.value=str(a/b)
    elif __operation.value=="cos":
      screen.value=str(a/b)
    elif __operation.value=="tg":
      screen.value=str(a/b)
    elif __operation.value=="!":
      screen.value=str(a/b)
  except:
    screen.value="Error"

# Adding the on call function to the numerical buttons
# i is going to change from 0 - 9
for i in range(10):
  cal_bt[str(i)].on_click(Get_description)

cal_bt["+"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["-"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["x"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["/"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["^"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["sqrt"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["sin"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["cos"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["tg"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["!"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["="].on_click(Get_result)

screen=widgets.Text(value="0")
logo= widgets.Image(value=image,format='png',width=150,height=150,)
row_0=widgets.HBox([cal_bt["C"], logo, screen])
row_1=widgets.HBox([cal_bt["sqrt"],cal_bt["^"]])
row_2=widgets.HBox([cal_bt["sin"], cal_bt["cos"], cal_bt["tg"], cal_bt["!"]])
row_3=widgets.HBox([cal_bt["7"], cal_bt["8"], cal_bt["9"], cal_bt["/"]])
row_4=widgets.HBox([cal_bt["4"], cal_bt["5"], cal_bt["6"], cal_bt["x"]])
row_5=widgets.HBox([cal_bt["1"], cal_bt["2"], cal_bt["3"], cal_bt["-"]])
row_6=widgets.HBox([cal_bt["0"], cal_bt["."], cal_bt["="], cal_bt["+"]])
widgets.VBox([row_0, row_1, row_2, row_3, row_4, row_5, row_6])

Esto fue lo que intenté:


  
     # These two objects are hidden
__operation=widgets.Label(value="")
__memory=widgets.Label(value="")

def Get_operation(obj_bt):
  symbol=obj_bt.description
  if symbol in "+-x/^sqrtsincostg!":
    operation.value=symbol
    memory.value=screen.value
    screen.value="0"

def Get_result(obj_bt):
  try:
    a=float(memory.value)
    b=float(screen.value)
    if operation.value=="+":
      screen.value=str(a+b)
    elif operation.value=="–":
      screen.value=str(a-b)
    elif operation.value=="x":
      screen.value=str(a*b)
    elif operation.value=="/":
      screen.value=str(a/b)
    elif operation.value=="^":
      screen.value=str(a**b)
    elif operation.value=="sqrt":
      screen.value=str(a/b)
    elif operation.value=="sin":
      screen.value=str(a/b)
    elif operation.value=="cos":
      screen.value=str(a/b)
    elif operation.value=="tg":
      screen.value=str(a/b)
    elif operation.value=="!":
      screen.value=str(a/b)
  except:
    screen.value="Error"
```

Intento 2:

```
# Adding the on call function to the numerical buttons
# i is going to change from 0 - 9
for i in range(10):
  cal_bt[str(i)].on_click(Get_description)

cal_bt["."].on_click(Get_description)
cal_bt["+"].on_click(Get_description)
cal_bt["-"].on_click(Get_description)
cal_bt["x"].on_click(Get_description)
cal_bt["/"].on_click(Get_description)
cal_bt["^"].on_click(Get_description)
cal_bt["sqrt"].on_click(Get_description)
cal_bt["sin"].on_click(Get_description)
cal_bt["cos"].on_click(Get_description)
cal_bt["tg"].on_click(Get_description)
cal_bt["!"].on_click(Get_description)


cal_bt["+"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["-"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["x"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["/"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["^"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["sqrt"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["sin"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["cos"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["tg"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["!"].on_click(Get_operation)
cal_bt["="].on_click(Get_result)
```